Tag wiki for MIPS assembly / disassembly, etc
I would like to have added [mips]as a new tag:

as quite a number of questions show up when you search for mips - 41 currently, although I think some might not fit under the spirit of such a tag
there is a tag for [x86], which has 47 questions tagged currently

if I click on 'Improve Tag Wiki'  for an existing tag I get:
You do not yet have tag wiki edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed., which is expected, but if I enter a non-existent tag from the TAGS page there is no button or prompt to add a new tag.
I just attempted to add on a single question as an edit, so perhaps it needs to be peer reviewed first.  
I guess my question is, how can I propose the description / edit for the tag wiki for a new tag if I can't see it yet because it is waiting for peer review?

Makes sense in my opinion. We have x86, ARM.. I approved one of your edits.

OK, thanks.  Perhaps my question here is redundant now...
